# android how to save custom checkbox state in sharedpreference and get it after app restart

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a `listview` of all install app. I am  using custom adapter now issue is this I want to save checkbox state when I check checkbox its state save in sharedpreferences and again when app restart and I open the listview checkbox state auto check which I save.  How to make this?
Here is my code

```
public class Listadapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> mListAppInfo;
    private PackageManager mPackManager;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> checkList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    CheckBox checkBox;
    boolean index[];
    boolean[] itemChecked;
    public Listadapter(Context applicationContext, List<ApplicationInfo> installedApplication, PackageManager packageManager) {
        //super(applicationContext,textViewResourceId,installedApplication);
            super();
            this.mContext = applicationContext;
            this.mListAppInfo = installedApplication;
            index = new boolean[installedApplication.size()];
            this.mPackManager = packageManager;
            for (int i = 0; i < installedApplication.size(); i++) {
            checkList.add(false);
            itemChecked = new boolean[installedApplication.size()];
            }
    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivAppIcon;
        TextView tvAppName;
        TextView tvPkgName;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListAppInfo.size();
        //return ((null != mListAppInfo) ? mListAppInfo.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
       // index = new boolean[mListAppInfo.size()];
        return mListAppInfo.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // get the selected entry

        final ViewHolder holder;

      //  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getLayoutInflater();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
        // reference to convertView
            holder.tvAppName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.tvPkgName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.ivAppIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            // holder.ck1.setTag(packageList.get(position));

        }
             else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
        final ApplicationInfo entry = mListAppInfo.get(position);

        holder.ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));
        holder.tvAppName.setText(entry.loadLabel(mPackManager));
        holder.tvPkgName.setText(entry.packageName);
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);


        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);

        if (itemChecked[position])
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        else
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);

        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (holder.checkBox.isChecked())
                    itemChecked[position] = true;
                else
                    itemChecked[position] = false;
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use your checkbox "position" in the shared preferences key :

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("yourSharedPref", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
```

And store my checkbox's state like this :

```
    if (holder.checkBox.isChecked())
        editor.putBoolean("CheckBoxState" + position, true);  
    else
        editor.putBoolean("CheckBoxState" + position, false);
```

Then you restore your checkboxes state by parsing this position :

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < positionMax ; i++){
        sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBoxState" + i);
        //Do what you want with this value.
    }
```

Comment: Actually, it would be better to save all your checkboxes states on your activity's onStop and to restore them in onCreate first launch (`if savedInstanceState == null`). And what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

holder.checkBox.setChecked() should read state, ex. from developer docs:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean defaultValue = getResources().getBoolean(R.string.default_value);
boolean isChecked = sharedPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.saved_state), defaultValue);
```

In the method onClick() you write state:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.saved_state), newState);
editor.commit();
```

Check [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).